# Program doesn't fully execute until it is manually terminated

Tags: java, arraylist

[Output achieved with using input "lolcat gg no ree"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgRNf.png)

[2]: Output achieved with using the same input (no code changes) https://i.stack.imgur.com/CquCt.png

If I just let the program continue to run it is stuck in a loop somewhere but upon testing each loop with a simple print statement I could never find it continuously looping over and over. I moved some scanners around thinking maybe that would be the issue however the problem persisted.

Here is the code to my main method header without all the print statements:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean run = true;
        while(run == true)
        {
            String blankSpace = " ";
            Scanner choiceSelection = new Scanner(System.in);
            String choice = choiceSelection.nextLine();
            while (choice.contentEquals("2"))
            {
                Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(getInput.hasNext())
                {
                    String currentWord = getInput.next();
                    wordList.add(currentWord);
                    wordList.add(blankSpace);   
                }
            String[] finalAns = morseCreator(wordList);
            for(int i=0; i<finalAns.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("test" + finalAns[i]);
            }
            getInput.close();
            }
            choiceSelection.close();
```

The method for morseCreator() is a method that takes the wordList ArrayList which is created in the above code and turns it into an array of strings and returns the array.

```
public static String[] morseCreator(ArrayList<String> s)
    {
        String[] morse = new String[s.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
        {
            String currentWordAt = s.get(i);
            morse[i] = currentWordAt;
        }
        return morse;
    }
```

I've printed out the morse array before it is returned and the array is working just like it should.

Comment: When are you changing boolean value 'run'?

Comment: @HemantKUMAR Farther down in the program, once that code is executed it will look down farther into the code and check if the choice == something else if not it defaults to run= false.

Comment: Furthermore, once `choice.contentEquals("2")` is `true`, it can never be `false` and you're stuck in a loop.

Comment: Also, the only thing `morseCreator` currently does, is converting an `ArrayList` to an array. This could be done with just `s.toArray(new String[s.size()])`. I suggest to drop arrays altogether and use `List`s instead of arrays, since they are more flexible.

Comment: @MCEmperor After looking more into it, the problem is the while(getInput.hasNext()), however why would the loop run continuously because eventually hasNext should turn false correct? When it runs out of new strings.

Comment: @mossy It's about the `while (choice.contentEquals("2"))` loop.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error resides in this loop header and your run Boolean value

```
    `boolean run = true;`
    `while(run == true)`
```

Since the run variable is true it will run through the loop once. Once it reaches the end, there is no indication for it to stop running, therefore it will create an infinite loop.